# Excel - How to show the last date different worksheets were changed

Tags: excel, vba

This is my scenario:

I have an excel Workbook with a number of different Worksheets. This Workbook is given to project managers within my organisation to complete. I have a Worksheet within this Workbook titled "Main Menu" which contains buttons that navigate the user to a number of different Worksheets e.g. The Registration page. The Workbook does not need to be complete in any particular order. This is so that users are able to return to a section if they do not have the information to complete it at that time.

The problem I have is that sometimes it may take a few weeks or even months for that information to come back. This has caused users to forget which section of the Workbook they were last working on. What I would like to have is a Cell on the Main Menu that will be next to the corrensponding navigation button, that will show when that section was laste edited.

I've done some researching and have been able to find out how to show the last date the Workbook was saved, but this is not useful to me as I need it for each individual Worksheet and this method only displays the last saved date for the whole Workbook. The code for this is as follows:

```
Function LastSavedTimeStamp() As Date
LastSavedTimeStamp = ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")    
End Function
```

I have also found other methods to show the last date the worksheet was changed but from the code I have seen, you need to put this on the same worksheet page, where as I want to display this date on a different Worksheet.

Any help would be much appericated.

Comment: This is a 'write me the code' question, isn't it?

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald - I read the OP's actual question as "How do I make code in a sheet change things outside the sheet?" The text of the question seems pretty clear to me that he's done research on what he needs to do, but found a roadblock he didn't know how to get around.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald I didn't mean for it to come across as that and it was certainly not my intension. Have added the code I previously used to show evidence. Might be helpful to allow the OP to rectify the mistake before downvoting. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close. While the *code* does need to be on the sheet that is changing, it can *reference* the `Main Menu` sheet, like so:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Sheets("Main Menu").Range("A1").Value = Now()
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your quick response. I was almost there, just needed a hand in the right direction. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: OP mentioned that he had learned how to put code in a sheet looking for the change. He just needed a nudge that the code could affect things *outside* the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

On your button click, just add this in before changing the worksheet

```
Sub Button1_Click()
 ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Offset(, 1) = Now()
End Sub
```

This will put the value of now in the cell to the right of the button. If the button takes up more than just one cell, offset accordingly.